Having trouble accessing database using a Framework-based script
I'm trying to get a client's php script working that's supposed to pull information from an external database hosted on the same site as the Joomla database. I'm getting a "mysqli object is not fully initialized" error - see https://tdev.threecats.digital for the error. This is a development server; the live site is https://taurususa.com, and you can see that it works.
The script was working fine until I moved it to a new server. One thing I do know is that the old server was using php 7.2 and MariaDB version 10.3. The server I'm trying to move the site to uses php 8.3, and MySQL 8.0. I wonder if the differences in either the PHP or Maria / MySQL databases have something to do with it.
Here is the script - the database information has been redacted. Can anyone see what's going wrong here?
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);    

// this file is in a subfolder 'scripts' under the main joomla folder
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// // instantiate application
$app   = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$input = $app->input;
$p1 = $input->get('serial', 'xxxx', 'string');   

$option = array(); //prevent problems

$option['driver']   = 'mysql';            // Database driver name
$option['host']     = 'localhost';    // Database host name

/// Redacted for Security ///

$option['prefix']   = '';             // Database prefix (may be empty)

$db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option );

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('status_id, tracking_number');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__t_so_master'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('serial_number'). '= '. $db->quote($p1));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
$num_rows = $db->getNumRows();
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option );
$query2 = $db->getQuery(true);
$query2->select('*');
$query2->from($db->quoteName('#__status'));
if($num_rows > 0){


    $query2->where($db->quoteName('status'). '= '. $results[0]->status_id);
    $db->setQuery($query2);
    $states = $db->loadObjectList();
    $states[0]->tracking_number = $results[0]->tracking_number;

}else{
    
    $query2->where($db->quoteName('status'). '= 9999999');
    $db->setQuery($query2);
    $states = $db->loadObjectList();
}
echo json_encode($states);


What PHP Extensions do you have enabled on the new Server for MySql?

Right from EasyApache4 (it's a cPanel server)
php-cli
php-cli-lsphp
php83
php83-pear
php83-php-bcmath
php83-php-bz2
php83-php-calendar
php83-php-cli
php83-php-common
php83-php-curl
php83-php-devel
php83-php-enchant
php83-php-exif
php83-php-fileinfo
php83-php-fpm
php83-php-ftp
php83-php-gd
php83-php-iconv
php83-php-imap
php83-php-intl
php83-php-litespeed
php83-php-mbstring
php83-php-mysqlnd
php83-php-opcache
php83-php-pdo
php83-php-posix
php83-php-pspell
php83-php-sockets
php83-php-sodium
php83-php-xml
php83-php-zip
php83-runtime

On the system that works do you have the php_mysqlnd or php_mysqli enabled?

Yes, both. I actually renamed that script with a "BKP" extension, and it didn't make any difference - I didn't even get a message saying it tried to load the file and couldn't find it. I have a feeling the issue is an older version of YOOTheme that doesn't work with the versions of MySQL installed on my servers.

I can't see the connection between the script you posted and the error messages being returned. The error indicates that the error is coming from YOO Essentials as it tries to connect to a database. I would be checking the settings in YOO Essentials for the external data base , in particular look at the HOST settings around localhost and 127.0.0.1. Or check that YOO Essentials supports the versions of MySQL on the new server.

Bingo! I disabled Yoo Essentials, and it loads properly. I do have up update the extensions anyway, so that should be that. Thanks!

The error indicates that the error is coming from YOO Essentials as it tries to connect to a database. I would be checking the settings in YOO Essentials for the external data base , in particular look at the HOST settings around localhost and 127.0.0.1. Or check that YOO Essentials supports the versions of MySQL on the new server
